# IE not clearing subsequent floats

Tags: css, internet-explorer, css-float

I'm trying to get two divs to float to opposite sides of the page, with text flowing between them.  The top of the second (left-aligned) div should be even with the bottom of the first (right-aligned) div.  The code below works fine in FF, Chrome, Opera, etc. fine, but they do not clear properly in IE.  Both divs appear at the top of the text.

If I move the left-aligned div low enough within the text, it works fine in IE, but that's not really a sustainable solution.

I've found multiple pages on IE CSS float bugs, but I haven't found anything speaking directly to this.

**CSS**

```
div {
    width: 200px;
    margin-top: 10px;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 1px;
    position: relative;
}
.wrapper {
    width: 600px;
    border-color: #FF0000;
}
.right {
    float: right;
    border-color: #00FF00;
}
.left {
    float: left;
    clear: both;
    border-color: #0000FF;
}
```

**HTML:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" 
"http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="float.css" />
</head>
<body>
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="right">
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. 
        Nulla pretium tempor leo. Vivamus mi risus, dapibus ac, 
        consectetur quis, pellentesque eget, sem.
    </div>
    <div class="left">
            Proin malesuada. Ut vel lorem. Cras rhoncus nisl accumsan 
            turpis tristique consequat. Sed lacinia ligula at nibh. 
            Morbi in quam. Morbi commodo nibh.
    </div>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. 
    Nulla pretium tempor leo. Vivamus mi risus, 
    dapibus ac, consectetur quis, pellentesque eget, sem. 
    Maecenas est dui, imperdiet nec, fermentum ut, 
    pretium a, orci. Quisque hendrerit interdum orci. 
    Nulla sit amet risus non enim ultrices bibendum. 
    Aenean arcu purus, rhoncus at, vestibulum vel, 
    volutpat et, nunc. Integer eget risus eget purus viverra 
    congue.</p>
    <p>Nullam vel libero ut purus semper ullamcorper. 
    Pellentesque mattis tincidunt odio. Nullam pulvinar 
    orci at dolor. Sed volutpat eros ac elit. 
    Praesent porttitor libero sed felis. Vivamus lobortis 
    pellentesque diam. 
    Proin laoreet massa ac metus. Integer faucibus lorem 
    molestie nibh. Integer id massa. Integer ligula ipsum, 
    pellentesque id, interdum at, pretium eget, orci.
    Proin malesuada. Ut vel lorem.</p>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: What is your question? It is definitely a bug, and it is fixed in IE8, but bugs in IE are not something new. Do you want to make it work in IE7 or just to make sure it is a bug?

Comment: Yes, I'm trying to get it to work in IE6/7.

Comment: Please state which version of IE you are using.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

IE7 and IE6 have a [variety of problems](http://www.brunildo.org/test/IEWfc.html) with elements that have both `float` and `clear` on them. In IE7, using `clear` on an element with `float` only clears the float below other floats *floated in the same direction*.

A modified version of the [easyclearing](http://www.positioniseverything.net/easyclearing.html) fix may do the trick, but don't get your hopes up. See this page for details: [New clearing method needed for IE7?](http://www.456bereastreet.com/archive/200603/new_clearing_method_needed_for_ie7/).

Bottom line is that you're probably not going to get this to work in IE6/7 without cheating: moving the div down in the text, embedding the divs in paragraphs, etc.

Comment: This pretty much put me on the right track. I've had to settle for a 1px-wide invisible div that I can float above the left-hand box.  That'll push it down below the 1px div, whose height I can set.

Not thrilled about the solution, but none of the other workarounds helped with IE6.

Answer (score 0):

I'm fairly sure this is one of those rare bugs in ie6 that doesn't have a pure CSS solution.

Try using the ie7 javascript - it may fix the problem for you: http://code.google.com/p/ie7-js/