# IE7 floats and clears not working as intended

Tags: css, internet-explorer-7, css-float

Have a look at this JSFiddle. I am trying to get this float layout working in IE7. Works in everything else. The two float rights should be next to each other. But in IE7 it messes up.

Any ideas on a fix? Thanks for you help.

http://jsfiddle.net/c9Wmx/4/

*updated fiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/c9Wmx/5/ <-- this works but is there any way to do this without using an empty div?

Comment: Serendipitious... I'm trying to solve the exact same problem now.  Will certainly share any solution I find.

Comment: Try clear:right instead of both? I don't actually have IE7, but I feel it might fix it.

Comment: @DanRedux Tried that. no luck. Do you have IE9? you can change browser mode to IE7 :)

Comment: Yes, I do. You could also try clearing the left side of the left div and the right side of the right div.. Also, putting div's between them with clear:both usually works cross-browser.

Comment: Had a look and it seems fine in my IE7 (apart from the fact that it took forever to load), looks the same as Opera/Dragon(Chrome) as far as I can tell. Version 7.0.5730.13CO. Or has the fiddle changed since you posted the question?

Comment: Looks like a duplicate of this question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/795161/ie-not-clearing-subsequent-floats Regardless, the accepted answer on that question explains the issue.

Answer (score 2):

You can give width to your `.page` DIV. like this:

```
.page{
    width:480px;
    float:right;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

See this updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/c9Wmx/6/

Comment: This works but the issue is the leftmost divs contain text and the widths change. So anything with less text still jumps up to the above line.

Comment: I am not getting exactly what you want to achieve can you make the example fiddle/screen shot with text so i can make my mind what to achieve.

Answer (score 0):

if it only happens in IE you can try putting the following in the head html tags.

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=7" />
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1">
```

Comment: Specifically IE7 does NOT work as intended.  Forcing later IE versions to render as IE7 will make the problem worse, not better.